# Separation of data traffic when data can come in any partition in event hub in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, data-partitioning

I am using event hub with 32 partitions and all pods are deployed in AKS . We have only 1 dev environment . I would like to know is there any provision that we can direct our traffic to us  . This will be helpful if multiple developers are debugging as we will be able to receive the traffic that we will be sending . Please let us know if there is a way to do it .

Comment: What do you mean by "direct traffic"?

Comment: And who are *us*? A single developer who is debugging, or all the developers that are debugging simultaneously or ...?

Comment: ... and how are you reading events?   If you're persisting checkpoints, are all developers using a single storage account/container?

Comment: It would be very helpful to add additional context and details.

Comment: We are using service that is using 32 partitions of event hub . Now , when we are debugging tests , request is going to one of the partition . So , I am facing the issue that I am not receiving the data that I am sending to the partition . It is most likely that if another developer is working in the team , then he may get that event . So , is it possible to isolate this so that we can work independently Eg: If we create our own consumer group . I am not sure if it is possible to do but please help me how can we achieve it .

Comment: By direct Traffic : I mean : if I am sending event to IOTHub , then I should be able to receive it event if other people are also listening to the partition .

Comment: Yes , we are persisting the checkpoints and all developers are using single storage account .

Comment: Please let me know if any other information is required .

Comment: There are couple of ways you can approach this(depending on the data shared atm):
- Allowing producers to write to a single partition and you can read from a that partition with different consumer.
- Augment the message to have a specific key e.g "mytest"(or team name) and filter records based on those test, preferably use a separate consumer group to avoid overlap between teams.
- Separate consumers for different teams/orgs
(Though i am not aware of your whole flow).